# Technical term for the Noun version of an Adjective and vice versa?

Tags: derivation

Given (as an example) an adjective form "liable" and the noun form "liability" what is the technical term (if any) that describes the relationships mapping one to the other?

Here are some other examples:

- available (j) & availability (n)
- red (j) & redness (n)
- culpable (j) & culpability (n)

The closest thing I could find was "derivationally related form" or "derivation", but I'd like to know the more specific way to describe the adj<-->noun relationships.

Comment: The usual term is 'de-adjectival noun' for nouns formed this way. The process involved is called 'nominalisation'.

Comment: Non-technical suggestion: *the noun derived from **culpable***.

Comment: Thanks @BillJ ... I did some more research and this seems to be the correct answer. If you add this as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *available* (adj) & *availability* (noun)
>
> *red* (adj) & *redness* (noun)
>
> *culpable* (adj) & *culpability* (noun)

The usual term is 'de-adjectival noun' for nouns formed this way.

The process involved is called 'nominalisation'.

Answer (score 0):

A ***cognate*** is the technical term used in linguistics.

> Cognate:  (of a word) having the same linguistic derivation as
>   another; from the same original word or root. ([Ref](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cognate&spf=1494861144555))

For example, you could say, 
"Available and availability are *cognates*." or
"The *cognate* adjective for culpability is culpable."

Comment: At first this seems correct, but then I found this on Wikipedia:  "For example, English ward and guard (<PIE *wer-, "to perceive, watch out for") are cognates, as are shirt (garment on top) and skirt (garment on bottom) (<PIE *sker-, "to cut")."  ..which seems too broad?  Am I overanalyzing?

Comment: If there is a more specific word, I am not aware of it.  Let's wait to see if you get more answers! ;)

Comment: 'De-adjectival noun' for noun so-formed and 'nominalisation' for the process involved.

Comment: Thanks @BillJ - I would suggest adding your insight as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I've always thought of cognates as similar words in two different languages--e.g., thaler, dollar.