# A word or expression to describe the set of words that are all related by a common root?

Tags: expressions

For example, the English words just (adj.), justify (verb), justification (noun), and justly (adverb) are all clearly a part of the same "family" although they each will have a separate dictionary entry because they are each different parts of speech.

How would I describe this "family" of words?  I want to say...

The word *just* is a __________ of *justification*.

OR

I always thought ***cognate*** was the correct word as you can tell from my ELU thread answer here: [Technical term for a noun version of an adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389319/technical-term-for-the-noun-version-of-an-adjective-and-vice-versa/389327#389327).  But, apparently, the word applies to the case where you are comparing words from different languages.  If so, what is the best term for words from the *same* language?

Comment: Words can be cognate in the same language. _Cognate_ just means 'born together'. So, looking at the descendants of the [Proto-Indo-European root *_gen-_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf) , we would say that all of the words are **Reflexes** of *_gen-_, and all of the words are **Cognate** with each other. So English _kind_ and _gentle_ are cognates, and so are English _kind_ (noun and adjective) and German _Kind_ 'child'. There is no specific term for the entire "family", since etymology is not really genealogy. More important is borrowing vs descent.

Comment: See also [*linguistic doublets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics)).

Comment: "The word 'just' is a __cognate__ of justification."

Comment: "The word 'just' is in the same __word family__ as justification."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the expression ***[word family](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_family)***:

> - ***A word family is the base form of a word plus its inflected forms and derived forms made from affixes.***  In the English language, inflectional affixes include third person -s, verbal -ed and -ing, plural -s, possessive -s, comparative -er and superlative -est. Derivational affixes include -able, -er, -ish, -less, -ly, -ness, -th, -y, non-, un-, -al, -ation, -ess, -ful, -ism, -ist, -ity, -ize/-ise, -ment, in-.
> - The idea is that a base word and its inflected forms support the same core meaning, and can be considered learned words if a learner knows both the base word and the affix. Bauer and Nation proposed seven levels of affixes.

(Wikipedia)

- Just and justification belong to the same word family. Just is actually the [root](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/root) word of that word family.

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  I think I will edit my question to include an expression rather than a single word request.

Comment: You may also say just "family" if things are clear from the context, e.g. *Just* is in the same family as *justification*.

Answer (score 1):

root [root, roo t] noun

12. Grammar. a. a morpheme that underlies an inflectional or derivational paradigm, as dance, the root in danced, dancer, or ten-, the root of Latin tendere “to stretch.”. 
    b. such a form reconstructed for a parent language, as *sed-, the hypothetical proto-Indo-European root meaning “sit.”. 
    http://www.dictionary.com/browse/root?s=t